# Amazon ElasticBeanstalk Log File

Tags: sql-server, debugging, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have recently deployed an ASP.net web server (together with an Database in RDS) into Amazon AWS, and I am facing some erros during a sql query execution. (SqlException)

I would like to be able to print those erros into a log file, which I have not been able to do yet. There is one log file in the Amazon Beanstalk dashboard, I have made many attempts, but my strings never show up there:

I have tried with `Console.WriteLine()`

Does anyone know some way to print strings into that log file? Or some other way to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see your messages in the log, you first need to log them.

`Console.WriteLine()` does not write messages into the log but it only prints them in the standard output. You must use some logging framework for this purpose.

[Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is one option, for example.

Also, it might be useful to read some logging tutorials for APS net: [this](http://www.theobjectguy.com/dotnetlog/Sample.aspx) one seems to cover a lot of use cases.